# What does the following TypeScript expression mean?

Tags: typescript, types

I am wondering what does the following expression mean `(<T = string>() => Promise<T>)` in the following context:

```
type Src = string | (<T = string>() => Promise<T>);
```

And used in the following function:

```
const handleSource = async (source: Src): Promise<void> => {
    if (typeof source === 'string') {
      setState((s) => ({ ...s, src: source }));
      return;
    }

    try {
      const result = await source();
      setState((s) => ({ ...s, src: result }));
    } catch (e) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.warn('[Image] handleSource', e);
      setState((s) => ({ ...s, isLoadingError: true }));
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 5):

It means that `Src` can either be

- a string, or
- a function that accepts a generic parameter `T` (which defaults to `string`) and returns a promise using that generic parameter to say that if the promise is fulfilled, that's the type the fulfillment value will have

So for example, you could have a function that looked like this:

```
function example1(src: Src) {
    if (typeof src === "string") {
        return src;
    }
    return src();
}
```

...that returns a `string` or a `Promise<string>`, or like this:

```
function example2(src: Src) {
    if (typeof src === "string") {
        return src;
    }
    return src<number>();
}
```

...that returns a `string` or a `Promise<number>` (because of the generic type parameter on the call to `src`).

Comment: very well explained!

Comment: As a note, it does not seem to make much sense to have a generic there, because it is not tied to any arguments. The function might be better off returning `Promise<unknown>`.